# Why do my fonts/layout change when in production? Tried Netlify and Github Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, github-pages

I'm trying to host a site on Netlify (or github pages), but for some reason when entering production, the fonts change, as well as some layout issues (See photos)

[image: netlify]

[[image: Actual Font[2]]

I'm not sure if this issue is due to CSS specificity, or if I need to declare the font-types somewhere; I've already added them to my `<head>` tag, and my css file has them each imported.

I've created a codepen with the code: https://codepen.io/aladin94/pen/BaowqgX (keep in mind the images and layouts will differ). Any ideas?

The font imports:

```html
<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/146c398456e6a22b45102120ae8a7679?family=Narcissus"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/21400dc679986534519c638136d62dbf?family=Rage+Italic" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried install fonts locally, If not then please try.

Comment: @MayankGupta How would I do it locally? By downloading them from the font website?

Comment: Yes @al feratovic, Downloading form the website or you can also generate all types of the fonts if ttf or woff file is available.

Comment: @MayankGupta Thanks. However, some of the font websites charge money for each font. Is there a way to avoid downloading the fonts? In order to allow different browsers to read them?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, that your production site blocks the insecure font.

See my browser console print:

Mixed Content: The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font

> **http**://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/146c398456e6a22b45102120ae8a7679.woff

. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You can change the behaviour for the specific font or you have to find a secure font for your case.

Have you tried this link:

`<link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/146c398456e6a22b45102120ae8a7679?family=Narcissus" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css" />`

**EDIT**:
As already mentioned in the comment section, you can find the sources in your developer mode of your browser. In my case, I am using chrome.

Try to download your needed files/ sources and afterwards you can try to upload it to your server environment.

I guess, it's not really a programming question/ solution because it's more related to library handling or security setup.

[image]

Comment: How can I change the behavior of the fonts? Also, here is the website on Netlify: [link](https://thirsty-yalow-686c3c.netlify.app/) . As you can see, the first slide has the font working properly, but the rest have the same default font. Is this because only 1 of the fonts is secure?

Comment: If I am checking the site, I can only see "font-family": "Helvetica";. What is the first slide? Rockstart Games? 
Downloading and hosting it on your on site would be the best solution as @MayankGupta said. If you open the source panel in your browser developer mode, you can find the urls of the font in different formats. But as stated, you must credit the authors. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, the first slide is the Rockstar Games slide. Most of the fonts were found online and some of the font websites charge money to purchase the fonts, so I tried importing them in both the html/css. Is there a way to write code statements that would let them run in each browser (woff, ttf, etc). Or I need to locally download the fonts first?